# Regarding a ring isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

Let $ R $ be a domain and $ f \in R[X] $ be a monic polynomial. Suppose there exists an isomorphism $ \phi $ between $ R[X]/(f) $ and $ R \times R $. Then show that:

i) If $ \phi(X)=(a,b) \in R \times R $ then $ f(a)=f(b)=0 $.

ii) If $ p(X) \in R[X] $ such that $ \phi(p(X))=(1,0) $ then $ p(a)=1 $ and $ p(b)=0 $.

I tried to show at i) that $ (X-a)(X-b) | f(X) $ so I wrote $ f(X)=(X-a)(X-b)q(X)+Ax+B $ and we must show that $ A=B=0 $. We know that $ \phi (f(X))=(0,0) $ so we get that $$ \phi(X-a)\phi(X-b)\phi(q(X))+\phi(A)\phi(X)+\phi(B)=(0,0) $$ Hence $$ ((a,b)-\phi(a))((a,b)-\phi(b))\phi(q(X))+\phi(A)(a,b)+\phi(B)=(0,0) $$ and I don't know how to go on from this and I also don't know how to approach ii).

I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: For i), the isomorphism sends the variable $X$ to some coordinate $(a,b)$ in $R^2$. Then if $f(X) =  X^n + a_{n-1}X^{n-1}+...+a_0$. How will the image of $f$ be like in terms of $(a,b)$? The approach for ii) is similar

Comment: Ohhh, yes , I see, of course it will be $  (f(a),f(b))  $ hence both coordinates are $ 0 $. I overcomplicated things way too much for such a trivial question. Thank you!